# Проблема со сменой директории в batch файле

Tags: cmd, bat

Нужно сделать batch файл для сборки проектов. Проблема заключается в том, что не могу перейти в папку Relesse, но она есть.
Привожу часть скрипта

```
echo off

set PATH_TO_SCRIPT=%~dp0
set DRIVE=%~d0
set DEST_DIR=
set PATH_TO_QT=

:checkParam

    shift
    if "%0"=="" goto ExitLoop
    if "%0"=="/d" (
        shift
        set DEST_DIR=%1
    )

    if "%0"=="/p" (
        shift
        set PATH_TO_QT=%1
    )

    goto checkParam

:ExitLoop

if [%PATH_TO_QT%]==[] (
    call C:\Qt\5.15.0\mingw81_64\bin\qtenv2.bat
) else (
    call %PATH_TO_QT%\qtenv2.bat
)

if [%DEST_DIR%]==[] ( 
    if exist %PATH_TO_SCRIPT%Release\ (
        REM Не могу перейти в папку Release
        cd %PATH_TO_SCRIPT%Release\
        del .y\* /F /Q
        for /d %%p in (.\*) Do rd /Q /S "%%p"
        set DEST_DIR=%CD%
    ) else (
        mkdir %PATH_TO_SCRIPT%Release
        cd /D %PATH_TO_SCRIPT%Release
        set DEST_DIR=%CD%
    )
)

echo DESTINATION PATH = %DEST_DIR%
cd %DEST_DIR%\
pause
```

Comment: Скрипт выглядит правильным. Может быть проблема в том, что скрипт-файл находится на диске отличным от рабочего каталога (обычно скрипты работают на системном диске)? Для смены каталога с переходом на нужный диск добавляйте опцию **/D** к команде **CD**.

Comment: Пробовал уже и с флагом /d, и с кавычками и без. И всё равно остаюсь на прежней директории. Даже пробовал pushd и popd. Но и они не помогли.

Comment: Я же написал, чтобы использовали доп.параметр. Это в 35 строке. Поменяйте на: **"cd /D %PATH_TO_SCRIPT%Release\"**. У меня срабатывает для разных дисков: c: или d:

Comment: @Daemon-5 Вот код по вашему совету
    `if exist %PATH_TO_SCRIPT%Release (
        cd /D %PATH_TO_SCRIPT%Release\
        set DEST_DIR=%CD%
    )`
И я не оказался в папке Release. Прошу прощения, если Вас не понимаю.

Comment: В какой именно строке не переходит?

Comment: после команды перехода **" cd /D %PATH_TO_SCRIPT%Release\"** добавьте строку для вывода в консоль текущего каталога: **CD**. Получается переход?

Comment: Оказалось, что в директорию я переходил, но переменная CD не обновлялась.